# How to install RVM with user that has no home dir?

Tags: jenkins, rvm

I have a user that has no home dir.  In other words, $HOME is not defined.
It is a Jenkins user that runs a job.  It does not have sudo access.

When I try to install rvm locally, it fails:

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io > install_ruby.sh
bash install_ruby.sh stable

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/.rvm’: Permission denied
```

So I try to trick it into thinking the HOME dir is the WORKSPACE dir:

```
export HOME=$WORKSPACE
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io > install_ruby.sh
bash install_ruby.sh stable

It looks you are one of the happy *space* users (in home dir name),
RVM is not yet fully ready for it, use this trick to fix it:

    sudo mkdir -p /ope.rvm
    sudo chown -R "ope:" /ope.rvm
    echo "export rvm_path=/ope.rvm" >> "/mnt/ope/ws/workspace/Hiptest Jenkins Integration Setup/.rvmrc"

and start installing again.
```

Unfortunately, this user does not have sudo access?

How can I install RVM for this particular job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using rbenv.  It worked out of the box.